# Caption in Hoverbox preview

Tags: html, css, hover, preview, caption

I'm using the Hoverbox image gallery (http://host.sonspring.com/hoverbox/) on a site, and I want to add a caption in each image preview (on hover, under the enlarged image). I've been trying it, but I only could get to do it in the thumbnail. I read somewhere that using a  for the image an another one for the caption would do it, but I'm stuck. Can anybody please help me?

HTML:

```
<ul class="hoverbox">
    <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" style="height:75px;        
width:59px;"/><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" class="preview" />   
Caption 1</a>
(...)
```

CSS:

```
.hoverbox
{
cursor: default;
list-style: none;
}

.hoverbox a
{
cursor: default;
}

.hoverbox a .preview
{
display: none;
}

.hoverbox a:hover .preview
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -33px;
left: -45px;
z-index: 1;
}

.hoverbox img
{
background: #fff;
border-color: #aaa #ccc #ddd #bbb;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: inherit;
padding: 2px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 100px;
height: 75px;
}

.hoverbox li
{
background: #eee;
border-color: #ddd #bbb #aaa #ccc;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
color: inherit;
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 3px;
padding: 5px;
position: relative;
}

.hoverbox .preview
{
border-color: #000;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
João

Answer (score 1):

Well, judging from your code, I would guess the caption is always displayed and some kind of beside the original image...

So, for the hover-effect, I would advice you to make a separate tag for the caption.
e.g.

```
<a href="#"><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" style="height:75px;        
width:59px;"/><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" class="preview" />   
<span class="preview">Caption 1<span></a>
```

Please note also, that I added the preview-class to the new tag. this will also hide the caption until there is a hover.
However, now the position is kind of off. so, there needs to be more css-code.

```
ul.hoverbox a:hover span.preview
{
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: -45px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Here I adjusted the top-statement, so the caption is underneath the image. This will probably only work with preview-images with fixed heights, though.

Another attempt would be using
`<li><img.../> <div class="preview"><img .../><span>Caption 1</span></div></li>` so the whole box appears with preview-image and caption.
Then you would probably have to format the span-tag with `.preview span{display:block;margin:0 auto;}` etc.

I hope this at least partially answers your question or helps you a bit^^

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Julian. It's an interesting solution! I've tried both ways, but they seem to do the same. In fact, what I want is to display the caption below the image preview, without overlapping. I've seen elsewhere a solution that uses two `<div>` (one for the image itself, another for the caption. Something like this: HTML: `<div class="imgpopup"><img /><div>Label</div></div>` CSS: `.imgpopup img {display: block;}`. Though, I can't manage to get it to work :\

Comment: @jaff `.imgpopup {
     background-color: #CCCCCC;
     height: 100px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -55px;
     margin-top: -55px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     width: 200px;
     padding:10px
}

.imgpopup img {
     background-color: #FF0000;
     display: block;
     height: 75px;
     margin: auto;
     width: 75px;
}

.imgpopup div {
     display: block;
     height: 25px;
     line-height: 25px;
}` When I understand right, this example-code will probably be useful for your given html. you will need to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I've used that CSS in conjuction with this HTML code (`<li><a href="#"><div class="imgpopup"><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" style="height:75px; width:109px;"/><img src="img/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="description" class="preview" /><div>Label</div></div></a></li>`), but all I can get is the caption under the image, again. I must be doing something foolish, since I'm far from being a CSS expert :\

Comment: @jaff ah, no, you're not foolish^^ to only let it appear when hovering you need to adjust the css. `.imgpopup div` becomes `.hoverbox a:hover .imagepopup div { display: block; height: 25px; line-height: 25px; }` and you'll need `.imgpopup .preview, .imgpopup div {display:none;}` that's also just an advice. As I don't know how it should exactly look like, I prefer to give you advices on what you may want to do. I hope it helps you a bit.

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can get. Thanks for all the help! [[]]